# _id field vs indexed date field to obtain latest documents

Tags: performance, mongodb

I need to be able to find the most recently added documents. I have decided to include a date field that contains the date they were added, this field is indexed. I am however, a bit curious about which query is superior, performance wise. Say I wnated to obtain the first 50 documents, which query would run fastest?

```
db.collection.find({}).sort({_id : 1}).limit(50);

db.collection.find({date : {$lt : new Date() }}).sort({_id : 1}).limit(50);

db.collection.find({}).sort({date : 1}).limit(50);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[explain](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/)** to compare the performance of the three query.

Given the three query and based on the description you offer, the second one actually dose a date field query before sort, the first and third one will directly scan the index in order(_id field index, date field index).
Which will be fastest between the first and third, you can find by yourself with the explain.

Besides, **if you need to find the most recently added documents**, then the order in sort should be like **`_id: -1`**, i.e in descend order.

A real case would be:

```
db.collection.find().sort({"_id": -1}).limit(50).explain()
{
    // BtreeCursor is an indicator that your query actually use the index
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id_ reverse",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 50,
    "nscannedObjects" : 50,
    "nscanned" : 50,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 50,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 50,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    // time used to execute the query
    "millis" : 5,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "_id" : [
            [
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "....",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```